# Get AD Groups Notes and Description Field From Importing CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv, import, active-directory

I'm trying to import a .csv file that contains multiple AD groups and I want to get only the notes and Description field. I'm currently getting errors, and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$ADGroups = import-csv "C:\Users\User\Documents\ADNotesField.csv"
foreach ($ADGroup in $ADGroups)
{   Get-ADGroup -Identity $ADGroup -Properties info, description
}
$ADGroup | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\User\Documents.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the error that I'm receiving:

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:3 char:25
+ {    Get-ADGroup -identity $ADGroups -Properties info, description
+                            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

CSV File first few lines starting at cell A1 and going down to A2, etc. All of these are AD Groups:

```
Domain Users
Washington Techs
California Techs
Nevada Techs
```

Comment: `-identity $ADGroups` should be `-identity $ADGroup` and `Export-Csv` needs to be piped to the resulting object of the above loop

Comment: Change `Get-ADGroup -identity $ADGroups` to `Get-ADGroup -identity $ADGroup` (note you've added the `s` at the end)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I edited my code with the changes that you've proposed and it looks like the same error is occurring.

Comment: What are the headers of your CSV and which header is the one that has the group's name or identity ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I don't have any headers in my current CSV file, just AD Groups. Should I have headers in it?

Comment: could you copy paste a few lines of your CSV to your question? need to understand better what are you dealing with

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I have pasted a few lines of my CSV file. If a .txt file would be easier for this case, I can try changing to that format

Comment: What you have posted _could be_ a TSV (Tab-separated values), you would need to confirm if those are actually tabs or not, the headers seem to be `Domain` and `Users`. If those are actually tabs I can post an answer to show you how to do it. The thing is, are you 100% the `Users` column has `AD Groups` aren't those `AD Users` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, the file is a csv, not tsv. Should there be a header in my .csv file before I list the AD groups? Domain users down are all AD Groups and not AD Users.

Comment: The extension might be CSV but what you have posted in the question is not comma delimited hence is not a CSV unless what you're showing is not the literal copy of what you have

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, correct, that is not a literal copy of what I have since I can't find a way to post my .csv file to my question. I can definitely change this to be a .txt file if you think that would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have a CSV (comma-delimited) and considering the `Users` column has the AD Groups you need to query, the following should work:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\User\Documents\ADNotesField.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Get-ADGroup -Identity $_.Users -Properties info, description
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
} | Select-Object Name, Info, Description |
Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\User\Documents.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: If you find that you run this and it is missing the first item, or there is no output, try adding the parameter `-Header 'Users'` to the `Import-Csv` call.